# pgfplots: Difference between "xmin" and "date ZERO" when using dateplot?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, axis, domain, dateplot

Assumed we have the following code:

---

**Minimum Working Example (MWE):**

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepgfplotslibrary{dateplot}

\begin{filecontents}{data.csv}
    Date;                   Value
    2019-04-01 12:00:00;    1
    2019-04-02 12:00:00;    2
    2019-04-03 12:00:00;    3
    2019-04-04 12:00:00;    4
    2019-04-05 12:00:00;    5
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[date coordinates in = x,
                     xmin                = 2019-04-02 12:00:00,
                     xticklabel          = \day,
                     table/col sep       = semicolon]
                     \addplot table[x=Date,y=Value]{data.csv};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}
```

---

**Screenshot of the result:**

[image: Screenshot of the result]

---

**Question:**

What is the difference between typing `xmin = blabla` and `date ZERO = blabla`? It seems to cause the same behavior?

Comment: The manual writes "pgfplots up to and including version 1.12 required this value." So this might be something that had been introduced and is no longer that useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: If I replace `xmin` in your code with `date ZERO` I do *not* get the same output.

---

`pgfplots` converts dates to a number, which corresponds to the number of days from a given date, I think. `date ZERO` is for setting that date used at the zero point.

The full description of the key, which marmot quoted part of:

> `/pgfplots/date ZERO=<year>-<month>-<day>` A technical key which
>   defines the 0 coordinate of `date coordinates in`.
>
> `pgfplots` up to and
>   including version 1.12 required this value. As of version 1.13, the
>   first encountered coordinate is used as `date ZERO`, i.e. it is assigned
>   automatically without user intervention.
>
> Users will never see the
>   resulting numbers, so one probably never needs to change this value.
>   This key allows to set the result as needed.